# How to get the Downling progress from the Flutter Downloader Package

Tags: flutter, progress, flutter-downloader

Im using flutter downloder for downloading the files from url. its working fine but i want to display a progress of downloads for user.

Can some please explain me how to get the progress data.

I got the progress Thank you.
class _Happy_hours_puzzlesState extends State<Happy_hours_puzzles> {

final ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();
ValueNotifier _progress = ValueNotifier(0);

@override
void initState() {

print("Init State+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

```
_progress=ValueNotifier<double>(0);

IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(_port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
_port.listen((dynamic data) {
  String id = data[0];
  DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
  int progress = data[2];
  _progress.value = progress.toDouble();
  print("inside port progress ${_progress.value}");
  print("status status status ${status}");
});

FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
super.initState();
```

}

@override
void dispose() {

```
IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
_progress.dispose();
super.dispose();
```

}

static void downloadCallback(String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
final SendPort send = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port')!;
send.send([id, status, progress]);
}

StatefulBuilder(
builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
print("inside StatefulBuilder progress ${_progress.value}");
return Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
child: Center(
child: ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
child: ValueListenableBuilder(
builder: (BuildContext context, double value, child) {
return Column(
children: [
Text(puzzleName,
style: TextStyle(
fontFamily: "Open Sans",
color: Colors.purple.shade900,
fontSize: 15,
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
SizedBox(height: 10,),

```
                                    LinearProgressIndicator(
                                        minHeight: 5, value: _progress.value),

                                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                    ElevatedButton(
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                        primary:
                                        (_progress.value<100 && _progress.value>-1)
                                            ? Colors.green: (value==100)?Colors.deepPurple
                                            : Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                          (_progress.value<100 && _progress.value>-1) ? "Downloading..." : (_progress.value==100)?"Done" :"Failed Please try again",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: "Open Sans",
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          )),
                                      onPressed: (_progress.value==100 || _progress.value==-1) ?  () async {
                                       Navigator.pop(context);
                                      }:(){print("Downloading");}
                                      ,),
                                  ],
                                );
                                // return new Text(value.toString());
                              },
                              valueListenable: _progress))),
                );
              })
```

Comment: Are you referring to this [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the progress value. I need to update the value on the alert dialog but the alert dialog not getting updated with the new value please help me with this